# Testing if DynaActionForm property is not empty using OR

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

I have dynaActionForm and the form contains two arrays(trip and route) in it.

Now I need to check if the two arrays are not empty in my jsp page by doing an OR.

```
<logic:notEmpty property="trip" name="myForm"/>
OR
<logic:notEmpty property="route" name="myForm"/>
```

How can I do the above?
I tried the following using JSTL:

```
<c:if test="${!empty(myForm.trip)}"> </c:if>
```

And it gives me an error saying that the property "trip" does not exist. I believe this is because my form is a DynaActionForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the Map from the form, and this map will be usable with the EL:

```
<c:if test="${!empty myForm.map.trip or !empty myForm.map.route}">
```